Conforming system type to a protocol with `@MainActor` isolation while disabling the concurrency check gives unexpected error
I have the following code that worked well:
protocol URLLauncher {
  func open(_ url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey: Any], completionHandler: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
}
extension UIApplication: URLLauncher {}

It worked well on Xcode 16 beta 1&2. When I update to Xcode 16 beta 3, it gives me error complaining completionHandler should be main actor. This can be fixed by adding @MainActor to the completionHandler:
...completionHandler: (@MainActor(Bool) -> Void)?)

However, I don't want to use any concurrency features yet. It's odd that Xcode even gives me this error, because I don't have concurrency checking enabled in my build settings. I disabled all  SWIFT_UPCOMING_FEATURES_6_0, and "Strict Concurrency Checking" to be "Minimal", and the language mode is Swift 5 (NOT swift 6).
Not sure if my code has any problem, or is it a bug in Xcode.

Various concurrency features are core parts of Swift and you cannot opt out of them. Generally, stricter checking indicates what defaults should be applied in the absence of an explicit marking. But if a type or function or protocol is explicitly marked, you cannot ignore that by changing your build settings. If a protocol requires @MainActor then conforming types must also enforce that.
What has changed is not that Swift has changed, but rather than UIKit and Foundation have added additional annotations. So you will need to deal with them.

Just checked that iOS 18 beta 3 added this @MainActor, which breaks the code. Do you think it's a bug that will be reverted? Because this means Apple's promise of "I don't have to change the code if im not ready" in WWDC 2024 is broken

I added @MainActor in my URLLauncher protocol, now it breaks in beta 1, because in beta1, this API in UIApplication::openURL doesn't have @MainActor

This is problematic because my code is a library and the consumer may target older iOS

Yes; it is not uncommon to have to add @available blocks for libraries in order to track which SDK they're being compiled against and adjust. This can be particularly challenging during betas since they all have the same SDK version, but is part of the process.

Is it possible to make UIApplication to conform to 2 different variants of protocol? How can i do that?
